# Why is the collection of all sets in a given universe a set?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

On page 13 of "Categories and Sheaves" by Kashiwara and Schapira, it says that

> Note that the category of all sets is not a category since the collection of all sets is not a set. This is one of the reasons why we have to introduce a universe $\mathcal{U}.$

A universe $\mathcal{U}$ is defined to be a set with some properties, one of which is the following:

> if $I \in \mathcal{U}$ and $u_i \in \mathcal{U}$ for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I} u_i \in \mathcal{U}.$

My question: given an arbitrary collection of sets in $\mathcal{U}$ indexed by a set $I$, how do we know that the index set $I$ belongs to $\mathcal{U}$ as well? If the index set always belongs to the universe, then why not change the axiom above to get rid of the assumption that the index set belongs to the universe?

I would appreciate any comments. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really much going on here - the point is just that a Grothendieck universe is required to be a *set*.

Comment: (In other words, don’t confuse yourself with preconceptions about what “universe” means! Here it is a technical term with a precise definition. Learn it!)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I apologize for my ignorance, but is any collection of elements of a set always a set?

Comment: @Hoji Yup. This is basically what the axiom (scheme) of separation says.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Alright, in that case, since a Grothendieck universe always a set, why is there a need introduce the axiom I mentioned in my answer above? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Hoji Because "is a set" is a weaker condition than "is an element of $\mathcal{U}$." The axiom in the OP basically lets you perform constructions "entirely inside $\mathcal{U}$" - vaguely put, no reasonably simple operation on sets will get you outside $\mathcal{U}$ if you start inside $\mathcal{U}$.